# How to install toolbox in Visual Studio 2008 Tester mode

Tags: visual-studio-2008, toolbox

I installed VS 2008 Team System and chose mode for testers. But there is no Toolbox in View (buttons, textboxes etc). How can I install toolbox or launch VS in other mode?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the tool box by clicking the Add or Remove Button on the menu bar selecting customize and moving to the Command tab. Then select the view category and drag the Toolbox command onto the View menu.

To change the mode you can reset your settings to a particular configuration by clicking

- Tools
- Import and Export Settings
- Reset settings
- Yes or no to save current settings
- Select the configuration you would like and click next